# Orbeon missing values in dropdown due to invalid session

Tags: session-timeout, orbeon, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm working with Orbeon 2017.1 which is integrated with Hybris.
We have a form which includes a couple of dropdown fields which as a resource uri call my service to retrieve values.

When the session times out for the user, and the user logs in to continue editing the form, the values from only the **first** dropdown field are missing (we noticed that this happens because the session id which Orbeon is using is still the old one -> which in return leads to an InvalidSession on our side).
We tried removing the cookies and also setting the session timeout in Orbeon's web.xml to the same value as we have it for our application, but none of these solutions worked.

Is there a possibility to somehow invalidate/remove the session from Orbeon or to somehow send a dummy request at the moment the form loads? Could we (and how) use this configuration property *oxf.http.forward-cookies* ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In our case, this was resolved by changing the spring security for the uri we were trying to reach. 
But it would be nice if we could also change the jsession id for Orbeon

Comment: Are you using Tomcat? If so, could you try  changing your `conf/context.xml` as described on the last bullet point at the end of the [page on session management](https://doc.orbeon.com/configuration/advanced/session)? You'll let us know if this helps.